Fusion Builder Design and Animation tabs not working in Wordpress editor
The problem is in the Avada Fusion Builder editor of Wordpress, practically the Design and Animation tabs of Fusion Builder do not work.
I can access the editor page, click on each component but for some reason the ‘Design’ and ‘Animation’ tabs don't work. Basically, you click on one of the two options and nothing happens.
It does not allow me to customise the modules.
We are using PHP version 7.4.33, Wordpress 6.3.4 and Avada 6.0.3.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
We have tried to update some plug-ins to no avail, and in addition the whole graphic structure of the site is altered.

Without specific details it's hard to tell (error logging / logs would be useful here) but, some general notes about the versions included:

Avada does not have full PHP 7.4 support until version 6.2
Avada does not have compatibility support for WordPress 6.3.4 until version 7.11.3 (support jumps from 6.2.2 to 6.4.1 between Avada 7.11 and 7.11.3)
Avada 6.0.3 recommends PHP 7.3, and is not clear on which version of WordPress it supports up to.

Source: Avada Changelog
I would therefore recommend, as a general fix, that you try upgrading your software to the appropriate versions. Be sure to take backups before upgrading.
I would advise against downgrading PHP and WordPress to attempt to match up with your Avada version.
If you cannot go down this path, you would likely have to dig into your PHP error logs and resolve any / all errors encountered while you are using Avada Fusion Builder. This is generally not recommended though, as it will likely involve modifying Avada Fusion Builder code.
